# Problems when moving Symfony3 app from dev to production server

Tags: php, apache, webserver, symfony, dev-to-production

I've created a web application using Symfony 3. In the development environment, I always use Symfony's built-in server and just use the command "php bin/console server:run". The app can then be accessed via "localhost:8000".

I've also defined routes using annotations in Controllers such as "/", "/about" etc. These pages can be accessed via "localhost:8000/" and "localhost:8000/about". Other links on the page that point to routes like "/contact" or "/users/1" also work perfectly. They will link to "localhost:8000/contact" and "localhost:8000/users/1".

Now, I move my application to the production server. On the production server, Apache2 is installed and some other people have developed Symfony applications on it. Their apps can be accessed via url like "example.com/apps/app1/web/app_dev.php" and the links on their apps have been pre-appended with "example.com/apps/app1/web/app_dev.php" automatically. So when the user clicks a button that links to "/contact", the link will direct to "example.com/apps/app1/web/app_dev.php/contact".

Now, when I move my application named "app2" under the "example.com/apps/" directory, I can visit "example.com/apps/app2/web/app_dev.php" without any configuration and see my homepage perfectly. Apache can automatically pick up my code. However all the links on the homepage will direct to "example.com/contact" instead of "example.com/apps/app2/web/app_dev.php/contact".

Can anyone help me with this? I'm pretty new with Symfony and Apache.

Or perhaps I've done the migration from dev to production environment in a totally wrong way? Any new ideas or proper way to move Symfony3 application to production server?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. I should use href="{{ path('about') }}" instead of href="/about" in all twig templates. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apache configured correctly? You may need to have a virtualhost configuration added to the server. You can find out about it on the [Symfony site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) for the specifics.

Comment: I have read this page before. I also see the "minimum configuration" section. However, on our production server, we don't use virtualhost. Other people's apps just work magically. I'm also not allowed to change the Apache config file. I guess there must be something wrong with my code?

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to your DevOps person. There is nothing magical about Server setup. It's a lot of very specific configuration. If there were some kind of open ended logic it could be utilized for malicious intent and should be changed.

Comment: In either case it doesn't sound initially like you've done anything wrong with your code. And the piece of the puzzle that is missing is not in your question.

Comment: I finally solved the issue. I should use href="{{ path('about') }}" instead of href="/about" in all twig templates. Thanks everybody!